# Import google icalendar to MySQL

Tags: php, icalendar

I have a google icalendar file. If I import this into my Mac Calendar will be the date "DTEND" 2017-09-02. That is right as well.
If I use the file with php parse will give me the date "DTEND" 2017-09-03.
What do I need to do to get the correct date?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:xxx
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Berlin
X-WR-CALDESC:xxx
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Etc/UTC
X-LIC-LOCATION:Etc/UTC
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0000
TZOFFSETTO:+0000
TZNAME:GMT
DTSTART:19700101T000000
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Berlin
X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
TZNAME:CEST
DTSTART:19700329T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
TZNAME:CET
DTSTART:19701025T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE


BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20170826
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20170903
DTSTAMP:20170115T115800Z
UID:7eecd830-1ee2-4c8f-82fb-e4f3283916d6
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20161204T172327Z
DESCRIPTION:DUMMY
LAST-MODIFIED:20161204T172327Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:DUMMY
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT


END:VCALENDAR
```

The php

```
$ical = new iCalendar();
$ical->parse($filename);
$ical_data = $ical->get_all_data();

$end_dttimearr = explode('T', $data['DTEND']);          
$date_end = date_create($end_dttimearr[0]);
$end = date_format($date_end, 'Y-m-d');
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Where did the iCalendar PHP class come from? Its not part of the standard PHP build. It has got a bug.What timeszone is your script running in? What not just set the PHP timezone to $data['X-WR-TIMEZONE'] ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps adding the timezone param to the date_create() function will fix it, like this:

```
$date_end = date_create($end_dttimearr[0],data["X-WR-TIMEZONE"]);
```

You should do the same with the DTSTART calculation too.